# Add a delay to the screen for Bluetooth headphones

Tags: sync, bluetooth, headphones, lag, delay

I have Bluetooth headphones (xiaomi airdots 3) that are connected to a computer.
When I watch video there is a delay (which is of course normal because it's Bluetooth).

I know that in [VLC](https://www.vlchelp.com/syncing-audio-vlc-media-player/) it is possible to change the synchronization between video and audio, and there is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-audiovideo-sync/mknmhikmjljhpccebpnplhicmcfjkgbk) for YouTube sites, but I am looking for a general solution.
With Equalizer APO I can add Delay to audio, but I need just the opposite.

So my question is, is there a simple option to add a delay for the **screen** (and with AHK I will set it to work only when the Bluetooth is connected)? And is it possible to set the delay to work only on the video playing in the background and not on the entire screen?

Comment: What you are asking for is not beyond the realms of possibility, but it is beyond the realms of plausibility. The amount of processing power to do that would drop your machine to a crawl… & imagine if you moved one of the windows whilst it was playing... Just use a wired headset.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I understand that adding delay only for video is more problematic, but at least adding delay to all the output of the screen should be simpler and also solve the problem. The question is how to do it.